# Is it safe to have HttpClient 3 and 4 in same classpath?

Tags: java, classpath, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

As always - legacy parts of a web application depend on Apache http client 3, new parts require http client 4.2.

Apache HttpClient 3 and 4 seem to live in different packages, so theoretically it should be possible to have both versions in same classpath. Simple test code works fine.

Are there any potential issues with this kind of deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I don't see any potential issues. But I'd prioritize updating the legacy parts of your webapp.

The only specific thing I can think of is that if you were using the both version 3 and 4 parts to access the same sites AND those sites used cookies to carry session information, then maintaining two separate cookie stores might result in strange behaviour.  For example, the server side might invalidate sessions.